# How can I allow all the subpaths after a domain in nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, forwarding

Below is my configuration of nginx proxy . I have to allow all the subpaths after example.com like it should allow https://example.com/test , https://example.com/vaid. These subpath are already present in example server which is accessible via internet.

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    upstream example {
        server example.com:443;
    }
    server {
        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass https://example;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It just have to work like https://example.com:443/*